# JPA ManyToMany - empty list in findById

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, set, many-to-many, findby

In my Spring Boot project I have an entity class User

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "applicationusers")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    [...]

    @Singular
    @ManyToMany(
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        },
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "applicationusers_roles",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "applicationuser_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") }
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

and a second entity class role

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Length(min = 3, max = 15)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "roles")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Singular
    private Set<User> applicationUsers;
}
```

In one of my tests, I try to store a Role with a User to the repository like this

```
@Test
public void createRoleWithUsers() {
    User newUser = User.builder()
        .name("name")
        .password("1234567")
        .email("hello@world.net")
        .enabled(true)
        .build();
    User savedUser = userRepository.save(newUser);
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    users.add(savedUser);
    Role role = Role.builder()
        .name("TestRole")
        .applicationUsers(users)
        .build();
    Role createdRole = roleRepository.save(role);
    Role foundRole = roleRepository.findRoleById(createdRole.getId()).get();
    [...]
}
```

Debugging this code, I found out, that `createdRole` has the users set as expected but `foundRole` doesn't.

[image: createdRole has the users, foundRole doesn't have users]

How can I get the users in `foundRole` too?

Please tell me if you need the repository-code - it's a very simple interface so I just skipped it.

Comment: I got it working by only removing the `mappedBy` command from my `Role` class. However, I doubt, that this is a correct solution and I don't understand why this is working.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified response, read the fine manual: [6.3.10. Configuring Fetch- and LoadGraphs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph).

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "applicationusers")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Singular
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

and

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    @Singular
    private Set<User> applicationUsers;
}
```

The manual specifies:

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>{
    @Query("select r from Role r where r.id = :id")
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"applicationUsers"})
    Role findByIdFetchUsers(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

The second `System.out.println` will give you a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    User u = save();
    Role r2 = roleRepository.findByIdFetchUsers(u.getId());
    System.out.println("R: " + r2 + " : " + r2.getApplicationUsers());
    Role r1 = roleRepository.findById(u.getId()).get();
    System.out.println("R: " + r1 + " : " + r1.getApplicationUsers());
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution - well as far as I could follow - but didn't succeed getting it running correctly. maybe I did something wrong.

However, what is even more strange is that I managed to get it working correctly by only removing the `mappedBy` annotation. I doubt that my solution is correct and I don't understand why this is working.

Comment: ----------------- LOL

Comment: @speendo: same thing here! Did you by any chance find out what exactly was wrong in the first place? I just got it working thanks to your comment. Phew.